# hibernate search between date return no results when records exists

Tags: hibernate, date, oracle11g, between

In my app I allow users to select a range of date to do a search, while these two dates can be the same day. These two `datepickers` get the day as `String` like this:

```
14/01/2016
```

and I manually add `HH:mm:ss` part to parse them as `Date` objects, and pass them into my filter for search. Actually, like this:

```
filter.setDateFrom(dateFormatComplete.parse(form.getDateFromStr().concat(" 00:00:00")));
filter.setDateTo(dateFormatComplete.parse(form.getDateToStr().concat(" 23:59:59")));
```

When I do such search with `hibernate.sql.Query` in my code with Hibernate:

```
select distinct myBean ..... where myBean.date >= :dateFrom and myBean.date <= :dateTo order by myBean.date asc
```

I can see the parameters passed in debug:

```
dateFrom =Thu Jan 14 00:00:00 CET 2016, dateTo =Thu Jan 14 23:59:59 CET 2016
```

No results are returned, in spite of that I have this record in my Oracle db:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM MYBEAN WHERE  DATE between TO_DATE('14-01-2016 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and TO_DATE('14-01-2016 23:59:59', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
14-01-2016 10:37:14
```

If I choose day 13 and 14, no results also. But if I choose 14 and 15, yes.

So I don't understand. I have seen question about, but I am configuring beginning and end of day correctly here. Why can't I get my records?

**EDIT**
The DAO method is implemented with `Query` and for some reason I cannot change it to `Criteria`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
filter.setDateFrom(dateFormatComplete.parse(form.getDateFromStr().concat(" 00:00:00")));
filter.setDateTo(dateFormatComplete.parse(form.getDateToStr().concat(" 23:59:59")));

criteria.add(Restrictions.between("dateField", fromDate, toDate));
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain it fully, but this `search` method is implemented with `Query` only, in other words, `currentSession().createQuery(sql.toString());`, because some `join` and `left join` and more details are added for reasons of flexibility and full control. `Criteria` is what I want to but I just cannot.

Comment: `Query.setDate()` or `Query.setTimestamp()`, which suits you, instead of  `Query.setParameter()`

Comment: Yes, I am using `setDate()`. Not `setParameter()`. I saw these parameters in debug, hovering over the `query` of type `QueryImpl`, in attribute `namedParameters(HashMap<K, V>)`.

Comment: Yes u r right. I tried `setTimestamp()` and I get what I expected. In other words, although I can `setDate()` with all info I have in `Date` object, in query it only searches with day and the rest are set all zero. Only with `setTimestamp()` I can pass hours and minutes into query. Thanks.